# Difference between Logger.getGlobal() and Logger.getAnonymousLogger()?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

Here's my sample code:

```
public class Logs {
    private static Logs logHandler;

    public static Logs handler() {
        if (null == logHandler) {
            logHandler = new Logs();
        }
        return logHandler;
    }

    public void logError(String message) {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, message);
    }
}
```

I don't really understand the difference between those two as they give the exact same output:

```
Logger.getGlobal.log(Level.SEVERE, message);
```

and:

```
Logger.getAnonymousLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, message);
```

Can someone tell me about their difference, so I know which I should use?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous loggers don't have a name which means you can't use the logger name as a [formatter pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-). Anonymous loggers do not perform security checks which means any code can change the settings of an anonymous logger.

Global logger is just the `System.out` so to speak of the logging API.  It is a named logger and it performs security checks if code tries to modify the settings.

The documentation recommends that you use [named loggers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger-java.lang.String-) if possible.

From the [GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME) documentation:

> The "global" Logger object is provided as a convenience to developers who are making casual use of the Logging package. Developers who are making serious use of the logging package (for example in products) should create and use their own Logger objects, with appropriate names, so that logging can be controlled on a suitable per-Logger granularity. Developers also need to keep a strong reference to their Logger objects to prevent them from being garbage collected.

From the [getAnonymousLogger​()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getAnonymousLogger--) documentation:

> Create an anonymous Logger. The newly created Logger is not registered in the LogManager namespace. There will be no access checks on updates to the logger.
>
> This factory method is primarily intended for use from applets. Because the resulting Logger is anonymous it can be kept private by the creating class. This removes the need for normal security checks, which in turn allows untrusted applet code to update the control state of the Logger. For example an applet can do a setLevel or an addHandler on an anonymous Logger.
>
> Even although the new logger is anonymous, it is configured to have the root logger ("") as its parent. This means that by default it inherits its effective level and handlers from the root logger. Changing its parent via the setParent method will still require the security permission specified by that method.

Also if you are to keep your example class, make sure you hold a strong reference to the global logger by creating a static final field.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the difference between the two.